# How to multiply the number of a string by a number

Tags: java

I am currently programming a progress bar in Java. I would like to add only every 10% the character `#`. What is the best way to do this? I would like every 1% the value output. I tried something once. However, it does not quite work. There is an error at `loader * (number / number), number)`. I don't want to write this under each other, but all in one line.

How can I improve it?

```
String laoder = "#";
int rounds = 1000; // Could be 10000, 250000, 60000, ... 
// This is 1% 
int number = 1000 / 100;
for(int i=0; i < 1000; i++){
    // This is X % 
    if(i == number) {
        // I want to print the # every 10 % and the normale percentage every 1% 
        // For example 
        // [#         ] 1%
        // [#         ] 2%
        // ....
        // [##        ] 10%
        // [##########] Done
        System.out.printf("[# %s                    ] \r \s%", loader * (number / number), number);
        // This work, but how can I combine both
        System.out.print(repeat(laoder , number / 10) + " \r");
        number += number;
    }

    Thread.Sleep(500)
}
public static String repeat(int count, String with) {
    return new String(new char[count]).replace("\0", with);
}
```

Comment: change the condition `if(i == number)` to `if(i%10 == 0)`

Comment: However, that would only do it for all 10%, right? And what would be for only 1% ?

Comment: you cannot multiply an int with a string. I think what you are trying to achieve is 
        `System.out.printf("[# %s                    ] \r \s%", loader, number);` Can you verify this.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, however I want all 10% to have a `#` added to it. Say that I have at the end of 100% 10 `#` stand there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a fun problem to solve indeed. Below is one way of doing it. All calculation is done using integer numbers (no floating point).

Just note that the total must be greater than 0.

Have fun!

```
int total = 100; // must be greater than 0
char[] progressBar = new char[10];
Arrays.fill(progressBar, ' ');
for (int progress = 0; progress <= total; progress++) {
    int percentage = progress * 100 / total;
    Arrays.fill(progressBar, 0, percentage / 10, '#');
    System.out.println("[" + String.valueOf(progressBar) + "] " + percentage + "%");
}
```

Sample output:

```
[          ] 0%
[#         ] 10%
[##        ] 20%
[###       ] 30%
[####      ] 40%
[#####     ] 50%
[######    ] 60%
[#######   ] 70%
[########  ] 80%
[######### ] 90%
[##########] 100%
```

Answer (score 0):

First off as @sanjeevRm suggested the condition on the iff will be evaluated only on the first 10% so you'd have to change it to

```
if(i%number==0) {
  ...
}
```

For the string part I'd suggest to build the string first and then print it to ease the manipulation of it

```
public String loadString(int hashCount, int maxHashCount) {
    String loadString = "[";
    //fill in the current loading percentage
    for(int i=0; i<hashCount; i++)
        loadString+="#";

    //now fill in the remaining with white spaces
    for(int k=0; k<(maxHashCount-hashCount); k++)
        loadString+=" ";

    loadString += "]";
    return loadString;
}
```

Now within the original for loop just call the method using

```
loadString(i/number, rounds/number);
```

SN: I'm not sure this is a fix to make but you wrote that number is 1% that doesn't seem right as you're actually dividing it by 10 and not by 100. Also to make it more dynamic you should initialise the number as

```
number = rounds/10; //number is the 10% of the rounds keep in mind
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand what you mean. I don't know the best way to get to the `1%`. Say number of `rounds / 100 = 1%` ? But then how do I check if it is `10%`, `20%` ,.... `30%` ?

Comment: At that point you'd just need to do `if(i%(number*10)==0);`

Answer (score 0):

This shows *one* way of coding it. You may want to tweak the rounding bits to your taste.

```
public class TestProgress {
    
    private static String getProgress(int current, int total) {
        float status = (float)current/(float)total*100;
        
        String bar = "";
        while(bar.length()*10 < status) {
            bar += "#";
        }
        while(bar.length()<10) {
            bar += " ";
        }
                
        return String.format("%3.0f [%s]", status, bar);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=0;i<5000;i++) {
            System.out.print(getProgress(i, 5000));
            System.out.print("\r");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! Only that writes it to a new line for me. But I would like to have it always in the same line

Comment: and can you please tell me how I can add the `%` sign to the `String.format("%3.0f %s", status, bar);` and the brackets with spaces? Example: `[#             ]` 9 spaces replaced one by one.

Comment: I changed your line to `System.out.print(getProgress(i, 1000) +"\r");` so that everything is in the same row, only the problem is still how do I get `%` signs in there and the `[]` brackets with spaces and if the round count is 5000 for example, then the indicator is no longer at `100%` but goes higher than that

Comment: You can still use printf instead of println, and for the format string check out the API documentation https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...) - it guides you to https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax which contains the answer.

Comment: If your round count goes to 5000, then 5000 as total work has to be passed in the getProgress function. I do not see the bar going to more than 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
System.out.printf("\r[%-10s] %d%%", repeat(percent / 10, "#"), percent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to print over the same line in the console is to print the carriage return character. In java code this is done using the following code.

```java
System.out.print("\r");
```

This simply returns the cursor to the start of the line.

The below code implements your requirements.

- It always prints on the same line.
- It prints the progress bar correctly.
- It prints the percent completed after the progress bar.
- It prints *Done* when the progress reaches 100 percent.

```java
int rounds = 1000;
int onePercent = rounds / 100;
int tenPercent = rounds / 10;
int count = 0;
String progress;
for (int i = 1; i <= rounds; i++) {
    if (i % onePercent == 0) {
        if (i >= onePercent) {
            System.out.print("\r");
        }
        progress = "[";
        if (i % tenPercent == 0) {
            count++;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            progress += "#";
        }
        for (int k = count; k < 10; k++) {
            progress += " ";
        }
        progress += "] ";
        if (count == 10) {
            progress += "Done";
        }
        else {
            progress += (i / onePercent) + "%";
        }
        System.out.print(progress);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException x) {
            // Ignore.
        }
    }
}
System.out.println();
```